# Yandex Карты API 2.0 : как можно скрыть точку с карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

у меня на карте 2 точки

```
ymaps.route([
         'Королев',
         { type: 'viaPoint', point: 'Мытищи' },
         'Химки',
         { type: 'wayPoint', point: [55.811511, 37.312518] }
     ], {
         mapStateAutoApply: true
     }).then(function (route) {
         route.getPaths().options.set({
             // в балуне выводим только информацию о времени движения с учетом пробок
             balloonContenBodyLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('$[properties.humanJamsTime]'),
             // можно выставить настройки графики маршруту
             strokeColor: '0000ffff',
             opacity: 0.9
         });
         //
        var points = route.getWayPoints();  
         //меняю текст точки 1
         points.get(0).properties.set("iconContent", "Я"); 
          //как можно скрыть точку?

         // добавляем маршрут на карту
         map.geoObjects.add(route);
     });
```

как можно скрыть значок с карты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
points.get(0).options.set('visible', false);
```

[GeoObject](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/GeoObject.xml)